# Lie bracket on the algebraic Lie algebra of a matrix Lie group?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a Lie subgroup of ${\rm GL}_n(\mathbb C)$. Also let $\mathfrak g \subseteq M_n(\mathbb C)$ be the Lie algebra of $G$.

I believe that we may, if we wish, get a handle on $\mathfrak g$ as follows: for a small enough open neighborhood $U$ of the identity in $G$, the map $\log$ (defined by a power series) is a homeomorphism of $U$ onto a an open neighborhood $V$ of $0$ in $\mathfrak g$, with inverse $\exp$.

In particular, if I wish, I may DEFINE $\mathfrak g$ as the linear span inside $M_n(\mathbb C)$ of $\log U$ for $U$ small enough. Let's call this the algebraic definition of $\mathfrak g$.

How can I understand the Lie bracket on $\mathfrak g$ given this definition? (Of course I secretly know that it's given by $[X, Y] = XY - YX$, let's pretend I don't know this.) Campbell-Hausdoff gives me the multiplication structure on $G$ given the bracket on $\mathfrak g$; here I am looking for something like the reverse -- a Lie bracket structure on $\mathfrak g$ given the multiplication structure on $G$.

Here's a start: Campbell-Hausdorff tells me that
$$[\log(1 + x), \log(1 + y)] = 2\log[(1 + x)(1 + y)] - 2\log(1 + x) - 2\log(1 + y) + \mbox{higher-order terms}.$$
(This makes sense: if $x$ and $y$ commute, then so do $\log(1 + x)$ and $\log(1 + y)$, so that on one hand, the Lie bracket on the left is zero. On the other hand, if $1 + x$ and $1 + y$ commute, then the logarithm of their product is the sum of their logarithms, so that the right-hand side is zero on the nose.)

Is it obvious how to take this further? Is there a well-known formula for this kind of expansion?

Comment: Some overlap with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1976319/, especially Dac0's partial answer.

Comment: If you want to recover the Lie algebra $g$ from the Group $G$, you just need to expand in proximity of identity, write matrices as $I+ \epsilon X$ and consider $(I+ \epsilon X)(I+ \epsilon Y)$ and then consider only linear term in $\epsilon$ eliminating second order terms. Anyway, good details of this whole interplay between algebras and group and CBH formula can be found Brian Hall "Lie Group, Lie algebras and Representation"

Comment: @Dac0 Maybe you meant something like $(I + \epsilon X)(1 + Y)(1 + \epsilon X)^{-1}$? The $\epsilon$-linear term of $(I + \epsilon X)(I + \epsilon Y)$ is $\epsilon(X + Y)$...

Comment: @Dac0 But what I want is to recover the Lie algebra structure purely ``algebraically" in terms of $\log$, $\exp$, and the group structure on $G$, without any kind of differentiation-like procedure.

Comment: @Dac0 I poked around the Brian Hall book you recommended, but I didn't find anything at all like what I was looking for. Is it possible that such a formula does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want something with $[X, Y]$ with $X,Y$ in the group $G$, indeed it does not exist since $G$ doesn't have a Lie algebra structure.

Instead, if you want to obtain the brackets of the Lie algebra $g$ from the multiplication rule over $G$ you just need to differentiate. In this differentation process you might consider elements of the group of the form $X = $exp$(tA)$ and $Y = $exp$(tB)$ and write something of the form
$$[ log( exp(tA)), log( exp(tB))]=[ log(X), log(Y)]=[A,B]$$ with $A,B$ in the Lie algebra and $X,Y$ are in the Lie Group. But you have to workout carefully al the process and arrive to something that -at best- is tautological

Other option is to work directly on the logarythm of the CHB formula as it is done [here](https://gyazo.com/ebe2cc9ce4aa4d365a9ea4e5fcd0d80e) in Richtmayer but can be found also in Brian Hall I think.

The main reason why you pass to study Lie algebras instead of Lie Groups is that Lie algebras are linear spaces and algebras with a bilinear bracket that is easy to study intead of studying a full non linear space as the Lie Group normally is. So in general Lie groups are not vector spaces and are not algebras (no brackets), only their tangent space at the identity is.

Hope this clarify :)

Comment: I'm not trying to put a Lie bracket on elements of $G$, and I do understand the idea of a Lie algebra linearizing $G$ near the identity. I just want to recover the Lie bracket on a small enough neighborhood of zero on the image of $\log$ without using the fact that I know that what Lie bracket is on $M_n(\mathbb C)$ and without using differentiation.

Comment: Perhaps this isn't possible; I don't know. BCH gives you the multiplication structure on a neighborhood of $G$ given the Lie bracket on the Lie algebra (and the $\log$ and $\exp$ maps), so I was hoping that something similar was possible to go the other way.

Comment: But I'm not sure that we're communicating here sadly.

Comment: Yes you definitely can and is just through differentiation... I'm not sure why you want the logarithm

Comment: I'm looking for a definition that avoids using differentiation.